# MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. [error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, cicd, build-pipeline, biztalk-2020

I am deploying the BizTalk project into Azure DevOps for CI/CD. In Azure DevOps, I created a new Agent called "newagent"[DevAgentPool].
I am receiving the above error when trying to build a pipeline. I have looked at the other answers to this question, I'm at a loss and was hoping that someone will see something I am missing. Here is the error log I receive: and I attached a screenshot of the error [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgDO7.png)

[File path generated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNtFH.png)

```
Starting: Build solution Orchestration.sln
```

==============================================================================
Task         : Visual Studio build

Description  : Build with MSBuild and set the Visual Studio version property

Version      : 1.199.0

Author       : Microsoft Corporation

Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build

==============================================================================
"C:\newagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -latest -format json

"C:\newagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [17.0,18.0) -products Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools -latest -format json

"C:\newagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\vswhere.exe" -version [16.0,17.0) -latest -format json

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"

"C:\newagent_work\2\s\Orchestration.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"C:\newagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=d80ba8f1-725d-43f6-9d47-7c1cdb3ff41d|SolutionDir=C:\newagent_work\2\s|enableOrphanedProjectsLogs=true"*ForwardingLogger,"

C:\newagent_work_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.199.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"  /p:VisualStudioVersion="16.0" /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="VSTS_f82be4ec-4c29-4226-9dfa-8eb0a30e25b0_build_9_0"

**MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.**

**Switch: C:\newagent_work\2\s\Orchestration.sln**

**##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'**.

Finishing: Build solution Orchestration.sln**

Comment: Check the paths in the solution file C:\newagent_work\2\s\Orchestration.sln and see to what projects it points and if those exist.

Comment: The error message is telling you the **exact issue**: The file isn't at the location you're specifying. You can run an inline script and run `dir` or `ls` (depending on OS) to investigate the directory structure and validate the locaiton of the files.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf whenever I build a pipeline, it is creating a git folder inside the agent folder, check this path C:\newagent\_work\2\s\.git . please check the screenshot I have attached above in error statement

Comment: One way this issue could occur is if you are referencing projects that are not below the .sln file folder.